# Live Video Streaming for Android App

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want stream videos to android app.What are the available streaming services.And how that video play in android app.I tired using vlc for stream the video.But it is not work

Comment: Try with Youtube application

Comment: @Palak thank you.I will try it.Can you share some tutorial link